# Spring Boot Actutor web metrics - disable (or group) http_server_requests_seconds_sum

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I have a service which handles quite a big amount of REST requests (arount 500k per hour). Most of these calls are GET request with diffrent URLs. To grab metrics from the service I'm using Spring Boot Actuator (services are writen with spring boot 2.0 ) with micrometer and prometheus. So on path: `/actuator/prometheus` I have all metrics for prometheus.

Now after around 10 min my services stop serving metric, and it could be because there are a lot of different URLs which cause a lot of  `http_server_requests_seconds_sum` metrics.

I want to disable this metric, or maybe group it for all endpoints.

Answer (score 9):

You could disable http metrics

```
management.metrics.enable.http=false
```

Comment: Thank you! This is impossible to find in documentation or even code.

Answer (score 0):

I found settings to disable this metric: auto-time-requests 
But to make it work with reactive endpoint I need also to upgrade Spring Boot to 2.1.0.
There is side effect i don't know any information how many RQ handle my service. 
Maybe now i change the question - is there any way to group this metric ?